# Why lastblockhash validation mismatch in integration tests but unit tests all pass

Tags: go-ethereum, testing

I have successfully built go-ethereum (release/1.3.5) and godep with go v1.5.1 on LINUX 14.02.  When I run 'godep go test ./...' all of the existing unit tests pass beautifully.  I can also run geth with testnet with no problems.  However, when I run the integration tests ('ethtest --test all' or 'ethtest --test --file BasicTests' for example), I see a "lastblockhash validation mismatch" in ChainAtoChainB_blockorder1.  At the Go language level, the problem appears to be an attempt to access a slice that hasn't been allocated.

I don't see anyone else reporting this problem, so I suspect that I've missed a step in setting up my environment, but I can't figure what I've missed.  Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: I have an accelerated testnet (see related post, it's about 15-20x speed) and I'm getting this error message every couple of days (5-7). I have to wipe the blockchain history to recover, which fortunately I had already automated.  I had just assumed it was my hack on geth to accelerate it causing some obscure timing issue...now not so sure.

Comment: My situation is as vanilla as you can get.  There are no changes to any code or contracts, so I have no reason to think I've caused it by anything other than a missed step in configuring the environment.